# Pagination doesn't work when use Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have 2 methods in controller. First method is List , main view where I just try to realize paging and navigation .

```
public ActionResult List(string category, int page = 1)
{
    ListViewModel model = new ListViewModel
    {
        Fields = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Order By Descending", Value = "OrderByDescending" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Order By Ascending", Value = "OrderByAscending" },
        },
        Furnitures = repository.Furnitures
            .Where(p => category == null || p.Category.Name == category)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList(),
        InfoPages = new InfoPage
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = pageSize,
            TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Furnitures.Count() :
            repository.Furnitures.Where(furniture => furniture.Category.Name == category).Count()
        },
        CurrentCategory = category,
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Second method is Summary (it is for partial view) where I implemented sorting with ajax and return PartialView with goodies

```
public ActionResult Summary(string SelectedValue)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = SelectedValue;
    IEnumerable<Furniture> result = repository.Furnitures;
    if (SelectedValue != null)
    {
        if (SelectedValue.Equals("OrderByDescending"))
        {
            result = repository.Furnitures.OrderBy("Price desc").ToList();
        }
        else if (SelectedValue.Equals("OrderByAscending"))
        {
            result = repository.Furnitures.OrderBy("Price asc").ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            result = repository.Furnitures.OrderBy("FurnitureId").ToList();
        }
    }
    return PartialView(result);
}
```

So Ajax works good , and it  sorts my goodies well,  but now  all list of goodies display in one page and if I go to second page I see same list. So my pagination now doesn't work , here how I implemented paging in View

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.InfoPages, x => Url.Action("List", "Furniture", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
```

I tried to add `Skip()` and `.Take()` to my result variable, but paging still doesn't work , what's a problem with my code?

UPDATE: 
I called Summary view

```
<div class="container" id="tableBody" >                
    @Html.Action("Summary")         
</div>
```

Ajax.BeginForm() called next

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Summary", "Furniture", null, new AjaxOptions
{
     HttpMethod = "GET",
     UpdateTargetId = "tableBody",
     Confirm = "Confirm AJAX-request?",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Fields, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedValue), "-- Select Product--")
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

Html.PageLinks it's html helper , it's class  MvcHtmlString ( I follow the tutorial described in Adam Freeman book "Pro Asp.Net Mvc 5" where he described about navigation)

Comment: What is `@Html.PageLinks()`? That is not part of MVC

Comment: And where are you making an ajax call? And where are you calling your `Summary()` method and what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi , I update my answer

Comment: Your `Summary()` method does not do any paging - that just returns all records based on `SelectedValue`. And you should not be using ajax in any case. And you still have not explained what `@Html.PageLinks()` is (although Guido Zanon's answer appears to be identifying one issue with your code)

Comment: And as a side note, using `new SelectList()` in the view to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is just pointless (as is the 4th parameter where you use `Model.SelectedValue`). Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Fields, "-- Select Product--" )` - although the `-- Select Product--"` option makes no sense either when the other options are to do with ordering your results

Comment: I would suggest you look at [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.InfoPages, x => Url.Action("List", "Furniture", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
```

for

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.InfoPages, x => Url.Action("List", "Furniture", new { page = Model.InfoPages.CurrentPage, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
```

Your Action is expecting parameter page as Int, you are sending x which is a InfoPage class converted to string.

The x.CurrentPage it's actually your current page, so you should change that for the page you want to display (e.g. x.CurrentPage+1? x.CurrentPage-1?)

Also I encourage you to use an already existing grid or component in order to resolve these kind of views, as in other case you will have to reimplement on every view where pagination is needed.

A nice open source grid that resolve ajax: http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: hello , thanks , but I haven't acess to CurrentPage when write x.CurrentPage , anyway , thanks for grid

Comment: Yes you have. x.InfoPages.CurrentPage

Comment: thanks but all I have after x is CompareTo , Equals , GetType etc. So I can't write  even  x.InfoPages.CurrentPage

Comment: Sorry my mistake again... you should use Model.InfoPages.CurrentPage

Comment: thanks , I will see in controller , there are wrong logic in Summary method , I should add correctly paging